# Alternative to the now-abandoned dbunit extension?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, dbunit

So I can test code that uses a database using PHPUnit, I just installed the [DbUnit extension](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit) using Composer, and I get the following message:

> Package phpunit/dbunit is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No
>   replacement was suggested.

I've seen [the issue on the extension being abandoned](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/issues/217), and people talk of rolling your own database testing code, but they don't go into any more details. Is there a recommended way to test database code using PHPUnit, or does anyone know of any examples?

(I did open [an issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3477) and asked the author of PHPUnit this, but his reply was quick and to the point - "No, there is not.") :-/

Comment: i believe you won't find any valuable alternative. just keep using dbunit as it is now (fork and patch if you really need to). not that many people dealing with raw db stuff now (unfortunately)